# create hidden textbox, change it value in javascript and get new value. c#

Tags: c#, javascript, web, textbox, request

I'm create a web custom control with hidden field:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    hidden = new HtmlInputHidden();
    hidden.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    hidden.ID = this.ID + "_hidden";
    this.Controls.Add(hidden);
}
```

I change it value in javascript on the page:

```
$(textbox).text("some text");
```

Then try to get this value:

```
string str = Request.Form[hidden.Name];
```

I get a null.... Also I tryed:

```
string str = Request.Form[hidden.ClientID]
```

and still get null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when accessing it from JavaScript you need to use this syntax:

```
$('#field_hidden').val("some text");
```

further, with the edit, I just noticed that you're not giving it a name as karaxuna stated. And finally, you'd need to make sure it's **inside the `form` tag** for it to be part of the `Request.Form`.

One other way of accessing its value though, even if it's built dynamically inside the `Load`, is to grab its value with the `Value` property. However, make sure you do that **after** the `Load`, in something like `PreRender`, because ASP.NET needs to have a chance to bind its value with `ViewState`.

Comment: also string str = Request.Form[hidden.Name]; must be in protected override void CreateChildControls()

Comment: @user2488500, yeah I didn't mention that because you already had that there.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a name if you want to get it with Request.Form